# A baby monitor using a Raspberry Pi to send push notifications when triggered by noise

Tags: python, bash, audio, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B with a USB microphone. I have used a combination of Bash and Python scripts to detect noise levels above a certain threshold that trigger a notification on my phone. The actual sound is not streamed.

The scripts are called using a command line alias for the following:

```sh
bash /home/pi/babymonitor.sh | /home/pi/monitor.py
```

### Bash script - *babymonitor.sh*

This uses `arecord` to repeatedly record 2-second snippets via a temporary file, `sox` and `grep` to get the RMS (root mean square) amplitude (see this [example](//stackoverflow.com/q/43415353) for sox stat output) and then `tail` to get only the numerical data at the end of the line. This is then piped to the Python script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
trap break INT
while true; do
    arecord --device=hw:1,0 --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -d 2 /dev/shm/tmp_rec.wav ; sox -t .wav /dev/shm/tmp_rec.wav -n stat 2>&1 | grep "RMS     amplitude" | tail -c 9
done
```

### Python processing script - *monitor.py*

This receives the volume data and compares it to an arbitrarily defined threshold that I chose based on testing. If a noise is detected in one of the 2-second snippets, a push notification is sent and it suppresses further notifications for 10 seconds (5 cycles of 2-second snippets).

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import push

THRESHOLD = 0.01 

count = 0
suppress = False

while True:
    try:
        line = sys.stdin.readline().strip() # e.g. "0.006543"
        number = float(line)
        if number > THRESHOLD and not suppress:
            p = push.PushoverSender("user_key", "api_token")
            p.send_notification("There's a noise in the nursery!")
            count = 0
            suppress = True
        elif suppress:
            print("Suppressing output")
        else:
            print("All quiet")

        # Count 5 cycles after a trigger
        if suppress:
            count += 1
        if count >= 5:
            count = 0
            suppress = False

    except ValueError:
        # Cannot coerce to float or error in stdin
        print("Value error: " + line)
        break

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Cancelled by user
        print("Baby monitor script ending")
        break

sys.exit()
```

### Script for push notification service - *push.py*

This sends an `http` request to the [Pushover](https://pushover.net) service, which results in a push notification on my phone.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import httplib
import urllib

class PushoverSender:
    def __init__(self, user_key, api_key):
        self.user_key = user_key
        self.api_key = api_key

    def send_notification(self, text):
        conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.pushover.net:443")
        post_data = {'user': self.user_key, 'token': self.api_key, 'message': text}
        conn.request("POST", "/1/messages.json", urllib.urlencode(post_data), {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
        print(conn.getresponse().read())
```

---

I would be grateful for any feedback on how I can improve my code or the conceptual aspects of this project. I am not very familiar with Bash scripting so feedback is particularly welcome on this.

1. Is it acceptable to have the Bash script and Python script called
   together with a pipe between them and both running `while True`
   loops? It certainly seems to work.
2. Is there a better way to exit? Current pressing
   <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will terminate both the Bash script
   (due to `trap break INT`) and the Python script (due to `except
   KeyboardInterrupt`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Bash

> ```bash
>     arecord --device=hw:1,0 --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -d 2 /dev/shm/tmp_rec.wav ; sox -t .wav /dev/shm/tmp_rec.wav -n stat 2>&1 | grep "RMS     amplitude" | tail -c 9
> ```

You can use newlines instead of `;` and after `|` to make it easier to see the separate commands:

```bash
    arecord --device=hw:1,0 --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -d 2 /dev/shm/tmp_rec.wav
    sox -t .wav /dev/shm/tmp_rec.wav -n stat 2>&1 |
        grep "RMS     amplitude" |
        tail -c 9
```

---

It's not clear to me why you're using `/dev/shm` rather than a pipe. Since you say you're not very familiar with bash, I wonder whether it's because you saw in the man page that `sox` requires a filename and didn't know that it's common for `-` to be used as a special filename to signify stdin. Untested, but on my reading of the man pages the following should work:

```bash
    arecord --device=hw:1,0 --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -d 2 |
        sox -t .wav - -n stat 2>&1 |
        grep "RMS     amplitude" |
        tail -c 9
```

---

I think the extraction of the amplitude could be more robust in two ways:

1. As a minor point, I suggest changing the regex to `"RMS *amplitude"` as a future-proofing precaution against the stats gaining a new stat with a longer name.
2. More importantly, `tail -c 9` is a very bold assumption. The Python program uses `strip()`, so you don't care about leading whitespace. I propose replacing the `tail` with `cut -d: -f2`.

---

Final version of the bash script if you agree with all of my suggestions:

```bash
    arecord --device=hw:1,0 --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -d 2 |
        sox -t .wav - -n stat 2>&1 |
        grep "RMS *amplitude" |
        cut -d: -f2
```

#### Python

I don't have much to say here except that `count` and `suppress` looks to me to be at least one variable too many. If you replace with e.g. `lines_to_suppress` then `if suppress` becomes `if lines_to_suppress <= 0` and instead of incrementing `count` you decrement `lines_to_suppress`.

However, it might be clearest to just eliminate them both and replace

> ```python
>             count = 0
>             suppress = True
> ```

with

```python
            for _ in range(0, 5):
                sys.stdin.readline()
                print("Suppressing output")
```

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I did indeed think `sox` needed a filename. Your points about extraction of amplitude data are great - I’m not good with regex! :) I’ll try all of these later when I’m back at my computer.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you might do to the shell script is to swap the commands in your `while`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
while arecord --device=hw:1,0 --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -d 2 \
              /dev/shm/tmp_rec.wav \
   && sox -t .wav /dev/shm/tmp_rec.wav -n stat 2>&1 \
      | grep "RMS     amplitude" | tail -c 9
do true
done
```

That means that you don't have to set a trap (interrupting the commands gives a false status that will exit the `while`).  Note that because we're not using any Bash extensions, we can run it with plain `/bin/sh`, which often has a smaller footprint than Bash.

There's no need for a temporary file - both `arecord` and `sox` will use standard in/out streams if not given a file name, so we can pipe them together.  This reduces fragility and may also reduce latency (as we can start processing the audio before we've finished recording it):

```sh
# untested
while arecord --device=hw:1,0 --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -d 2 \
      | sox -t .wav - -n stat 2>&1 \
      | grep "RMS     amplitude" | tail -c 9
```

You might also be able to use a smaller audio format - `8U` should be sufficient for simple amplitude measurement, and the rate can be more in the speech range (the `arecord` default of 8kHz should be fine).

I believe that `sox` or `rec` ought to be able to read directly from the microphone, and to do the silence-detection itself using the `silence` effect.  I'm not a frequent user of `sox` so you should consult the manpage yourself for the details.

Comment: I also wondered about `sox -d` as a way of eliminating `arecord` from the pipeline, but I couldn't figure out from the manpage how to specify the 2 second time limit.

Comment: One of the examples in the man page "*stops after it sees 10 minutes of silence*" - I think perhaps that could be adapted to this purpose?  There's also the `trim` filter, which might warrant investigation.  Another avenue of research would be to bring the script's function into Python, using `pysox`.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I’m going to try them later.